# Oracle SQL: How to calculate AVG on case-sensitive columns?

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to calculate the average price per brand of the table below:

```
SELECT * FROM VENDOR;
```

[image]

**Expected result:**

[image]

I did some tests but they do not calculate and group the AVG per brand,
For example:

```
CREATE VIEW AVERAGE_PRICE  AS 
SELECT LOWER (BRAND) as BRAND, AVG (PRICE) as PRICE
FROM VENDOR
GROUP BY BRAND;
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be

```
group by lower(brand)
```